# dcraw issue with fuji x raf

Tags: 12.04, compiling, photo

I have ubuntu 12.04 lts 64bits.
I can not decode raw raf fuji X file with the dcraw utility (report error :  Corrupt data near 0xdc800) as availaible in the "logithèque" dcraw 8.99-1build1
This is fixed in a new version of this utilities, I compiled the source and install a new dcraw that work fine.
But dcraw is used directly or inidirectly by other projects :
   ufraw, gimp-ufraw, darktable, rawtherapy ...
Is it possible to have a have a less tedious solution than compile and reinstall all these projects to be able to handle my raf file with theses tools?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing, you should do, is writing a bug report. The [bug page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dcraw/+bugs) at Launchpad doesn't list your bug so far. So if you describe the problem and what helped you the maintainer might release a new version soon.

Building the source from source seems the best solution at the moment. In the case of dcraw it is sufficient to just replace the executable. If you want a more nice and clean solution I would suggest building an own Ubuntu deb package. You can use `apt-get source dcraw` to retrieve the old source files. Now you replace the old `dcraw.c` with the new one and try to rebuild the package. Now you get a new deb file, which you can install using `dpkg` or Software Center.

A third option is to use a package from another distribution. For instance OpenSUSE has a [newer version than Ubuntu](http://pkgs.org/download/dcraw). You can download the RPM file and use `alien` to make a deb package from the RPM.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an old report with no accepted answer, I'll suggest testing current versions of dcraw and ufraw. At least the latter should have improved Fuji X support by now (>0.20).